# Get country from Locale JSF from client

Tags: jsf, client, locale, country

how can I get the current Country from the client?

I try this:

```
Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

But I got only the locale like "en".
But how can I get the country of the client?

Thank you so much for answers.

Comment: Locale method is not always reliable and true. You need to analyze the IP address, the Timezone and Locale , then find the most suitable and best matching country. Proxies make the job harder.

Comment: Have you an example how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have any working code to post here. Anyway, your method is only getting the Locale of the client's **browser** , and do not provide any information related to the country where the request is coming from , therefore the method probably doesn't satisfy the requirements. It's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

locale.getCountry();

Comment: This returns the country's name of the locale, not that of the user.